# Sharepoint 2013 Permissions: Everyone cannot read jquery lib?

Tags: jquery, sharepoint, permissions

I have a site where I use jquery and custom scripts (stored in Site Assets).
For me as a member of the "Designer" and "Owner" group, everything works perfectly.

However, other ("normal") users get errors like `"$" is undefined`. I guess, the jquery library is not being loaded?

I tried to add `Everyone` and also `NT AUTHORITY\authenticated users` to the Visitors group. But this doesn't help.

The inheritance is not broken, all the site uses the same permissions for all pages/libraries etc.

How can I set the permisssions so that everyone can "see" the pages including the scripts as I do?

***edit:***
I have no option to "publish" the jquery file. When I check-out and check-in again, there is no effect.
Also, the script path is correct.

Comment: open `Site Assets` library, from ribbon select `Sharing` then `Adnvanced`. User.aspx should appear where you can `Check Permissions` for specific user.

Comment: maybe your `Visitors` group does not have access to `Site Assets` library

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the cause:

All the permissions were correct. Also `Check Permissions` for `Everyone` was showing the correct entries.

The solution was that the **Master Page** had been customized and had to be published as a **Major Version**!
Otherwise, "normal" users were shown an older version of the customized master page where jquery was not included yet.